# JavaScript - multiple global objects in multiple HTML frames?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Do we have multiple (different) global objects in a multi-frame frameset HTML?

It's common to use:

```
 if(window.top != window.self) {
   alert("We're in a frame");
 }
```

where `window` is a property of the `[[global]]` object like `self` is, and both are references to `[[global]]` object itself. But, if `window.top` refers to the topmost `window` frame object and therefore to the `[[global]]` object, how many `[[global]]` objects do we have? Or maybe the window DOM part is changed only?

Comment: What do you mean by "we", in each iframe there is only one global window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `document` (therefore each frame) has its own `window` object.

The `window` object is not a unique singleton. It's just an instance of `Window`. One is created for each `document`, and can be accessed through `document.defaultView`.

If and only if two pieces of your application share a `document`, they share a `window`.

There is no `[[global]]` object: global scope is just a way of conveniently accessing the current `window`.

Comment: @umop episdn: "What I've learned about the global object in ECMAScript is the following: Global object is the object which is created before entering any execution context; this object exists in the single copy, its properties are accessible from any place of the program, the life cycle of the global object ends with program end." you can read about in [Variable object in global context](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/#variable-object-in-global-context) here. So now I'm a litte confused.

Comment: You can't really access it as an object, it's more of a namespace. The important thing is that each frame has a different `window`.